# Localization of Titanimum Mobile application

Tags: iphone, android, localization, titanium-mobile

I am creating android/iphone application using Titanium Studio and right now stack with a question of how to consider localization and different language support. I dont want to end up  with different applications each for one language. So I started with official Titanium suggestion http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Internationalizing+your+Application

but I still do not get if using such way will make sure after I upload my application to stores it will pull the right language automatically or how exactly does it work or should be done?

Could anyone please suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this translation is automatic based on the language the device is configured for.  Here is a snippet from the updated [internationalization documentation](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Internationalization) concerning testing:

**Testing Languages**

When building internationalized apps, you'll need to test each of the supported languages. You can do so either on-device or in the simulator/emulator. In each case, you configure the device's language settings to change locales.

To set the language on iOS:,

- Tap Settings, General, International.
- Tap Language
- Select the language to use. Tap Done (or OK).
- Optionally, in Settings, tap General, International, Region Format to specify your locale format for dates and times.

To set the language on Android:

- Open your Android Settings
- Tap Language and Keyboard.
- Tap Select language
- Tap the language to use